# Get button value printed by php and process them via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic table where results from database are printed.

```
<table id="table" class="table datatable-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-teal">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Datum & Vrijeme</th>
            <th>Stavka</th>                                                 
            <th><center>Izabrana količina</center></th>
            <th><center><i class="icon-pencil"></i></center></th>
            <th><center><i class="icon-bin"></i></center></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            $i = 1;
            while ($r=$q->fetch()) {
                $a = 0;
                $a += 1;

                $id = $r['Id'];
                $datum = $r['Datum'];                                           
                $time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($datum));
                $time2 = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($datum));
                $stavka = $r['Stavka'];                                         
                $kolicina = $r['Kolicina'];

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; $i++; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $time2 .' & '.$time; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $stavka; ?></td>
            <td class="nr"><center><?php echo $kolicina; ?></center></td>
            <td><center><button type="button" value="<?php echo $id?>"  name="izmjena" onClick="showDiv()"><i class="icon-pencil text-danger"></i></center></button>
            </td>                                                   
            <td><center><button type="submit" value="<?php echo $id ;?>" name="brisi" class="icon-bin text-danger"></button></center></td>
        </tr> 
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    <!--<a onClick="window.open('edit/korpa.php?id= <?=$r['Id']?>','E-cart','width=800,height=500,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes')"> -->
</table>
```

In the table I have button for editing "Kolicina". Once I click on button in a row, It needs to open div.

In that div, I need to pass values and print them by using js. Once I do that, I need to save it in db by php

Once I click on button div below shows (it works).

```
<div class="col-lg-9" id="IzmjenaDiv" style="display:none;" >                                   
    <div class="panel panel-flat">      
        <table class="table table-bordered">                                            
            <tr>
                <th class="">Količina</th>
                <td class=""><input type="text" id="id" value="" class="form-control text-info border-info"></td>
                <td class=""><input type="text" id="kolicina" name="kolicina" placeholder="Upišite novu količinu" class="form-control text-danger border-danger"></td>
                <td class="">
                    <select class="form-control" id="mjera" name="mjera">
                        <option value="KG">KG </option> 
                        <option value="KOM">KOM </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>                                   
        </table><hr/>   
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="savechanges()"> Snimi <i class="icon-play3 position-right"></i></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                                        
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/> 
    </div>          
</div>
```

I need to make script which willl get two values from row, one from button one from row "Kolicina". Then I need to print those values in div that shows on click.
I made script but it automatically closes div I want to open.

```
<script>
    function showDiv() {

       document.getElementById('IzmjenaDiv').style.display = "block";

            var y = $(object).parent("center").parent("td").parent("tr").find(".nr center").text();
            var x = $(object).attr("value");        

            window.location.href = "korpa.php?w1=" + x + "&w2=" + y; 


    }
</script>
```

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Pass the reference of the TD tag as an argument in the showDiv() function. Change the HTML:

```
<td><center><button type="button" value="<?php echo $id?>"  name="izmjena" onClick="showDiv(this)"><i class="icon-pencil text-danger"></i></center></button>
                </td>
```

Javascript:

```
function showDiv(obj) {

       document.getElementById('IzmjenaDiv').style.display = "block";
       var id = $(obj).parent("center").parenrt("td").parent("tr").find(".nr center").text();

    }
```

Comment: Can you try again?

Comment: It is good now I got id value, but the problem is in script now it automatically closes div i open